# Javascript: Push array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (global scope):

```
objects =[{id:"0",radius:3,},{id:"1",radius:2,}].
```

This array is being manipulated by changing the single objects:

```
objects =[{id:"0",radius:4,},{id:"1",radius:5,}].
```

or by pushing new objects to the array:

```
objects =[{id:"0",radius:4,},{id:"1",radius:5,},{id:"2",radius:3,}].
```

After each manipulation, I want to save the entire array to another array called "history" to be able to recall each state.

I've tried:

```
var history_obj =[];

var history_index = 0;

function save_to_history(){history_obj[history_index]=objects; history_index++;}
```

and also:

```
function save_to_history(){history_obj.push(objects); history_index++;}
```

I've debugged the script and found out, that after running the save_to_history() function n times my history_obj contains a number of n arrays, however all arrays are the same (the one that would be supposed to be the last one to be pushed)  not [[state1],[state2],[state3]] but [[state3],[state3],[state3]].

I've read in this forum, that this Problem has to do with the scope.

So I've tried:

```
function save_to_history(){
var status = objects; 
history_obj[history_index]=status;
history_index++;}
```

The result is the same.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to push the current array as a string to an array.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same reference into your history, you need to first clone it and then add it in, like so:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

This should solve the issue:

```
function save_to_history(){
    history_obj.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objects)))
}
```

as you need to **deepcopy** the object else it'll keep on changing, whenever your `objects` changes and consequently all the values will be same, which exactly is what you're getting.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do the job.